# PWA not showing "add to desktop" popup on Android (does show in Chrome and Brave browsers)

Tags: progressive-web-apps, service-worker

I've followed all the required steps, made sure everything that should be in the manifest is there:

- start url
- name
- shortname
- description

Scope is set to / and all the icons are there.

```
{
  "description": "C5 manifest",
  "name": "C5",
  "short_name": "c5",
  "icons": [
    {
      "src": "/icons/icon_512x512.png",
      "sizes": "512x512",
      "type": "image/png",
      "purpose": "any maskable"
    },
    {
      "src": "/icons/icon_384x384.png",
      "sizes": "384x384",
      "type": "image/png",
      "purpose": "any maskable"
    },
    {
      "src": "/icons/icon_192x192.png",
      "sizes": "192x192",
      "type": "image/png",
      "purpose": "any maskable"
    },
    {
      "src": "/icons/icon_152x152.png",
      "sizes": "152x152",
      "type": "image/png",
      "purpose": "any maskable"
    },
    {
      "src": "/icons/icon_144x144.png",
      "sizes": "144x144",
      "type": "image/png",
      "purpose": "any maskable"
    },
    {
      "src": "/icons/icon_120x120.png",
      "sizes": "120x120",
      "type": "image/png",
      "purpose": "any maskable"
    },
    {
      "src": "/icons/icon_64x64.png",
      "sizes": "64x64",
      "type": "image/png",
      "purpose": "any maskable"
    },
    {
      "src": "/icons/icon_32x32.png",
      "sizes": "32x32",
      "type": "image/png",
      "purpose": "any maskable"
    }
  ],
  "start_url": "https://c5.kwyjibo.app/",
  "display": "standalone",
  "background_color": "#FF13DB",
  "theme_color": "#FF7D13",
  "lang": "en"
}
```

I've also used Lighthouse and it passes all their checks. However, the "Add to home" popup does not get shown when opening it in either Chrome or Firefox on Android.

I've added event listeners for both load and beforeinstallprompt events, and it does look like they are called.

Can anyone perhaps shed some light? I'm at my wits end. The site is https://c5.kwyjibo.app/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone else finding this. The problem was that the service worker did not support offline. Changing it to support offline and making sure I have an offline.html file in the root solved the problem.